# Counting Maximum number of Rows After applying groupby()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows -
`FileName        PageNo     LineNo  Name      Class_par_ratio
17973375 - 1    TM000010    82     POWDERS   MILK
17973375 - 1    TM000015    49     milk      MILK
17973375 - 1    TM000015    49     Dairy     OTHER FOODS
17973375 - 1    TM000016    11     Fat       ANIMAL AND VEGETABLE OIL
17973375 - 1    TM000006    79     POWDER    MILK
17973375 - 1    TM000016    9      Milk      MILK`

I want to group the output by FileName and Class_par_ratio, also I want to find the frequency of Class_par_ratio and place it in a column - frequency , and then I want to find the max frequency in another column named 'max freq'.

The output would somewhat look like -

```
FileName      Class_par_ratio           Frequency    Max_Class     Max Freq.
17743633 - 1  OTHER FOODS               2            OTHER GOODS    4
              OTHER GOODS               4                  
17743634 - 1  MEAT                      12           MEAT           12
17743634 - 2  MEAT                       1           MEAT            1
17743635 - 1  MEAT                      83           MEAT           83
              OTHER GOODS               2      
17743642 - 1  MEAT                      43           MEAT           43
              OTHER GOODS               2                  
17743739 - 1  OTHER GOODS               3            OTHER GOODS     3
```

The Codes snippets that I have tried Till now are -

```
1) df.groupby(['FileName'])['Class_par_ratio'].value_counts()
```

The output I'm getting here is :-

```
FileName      Class_par_ratio
17743633 - 1  OTHER GOODS         8
17743634 - 1  MEAT AND LIVESTOCK 15
17743634 - 2  PETROLEUM           1
17743635 - 1  MEAT AND LIVESTOCK 87
```

Another one is -

```
2) coll_g = coll.groupby(['FileName', 'Class_par_ratio']).size().groupby(              
['FileName', 'Class_par_ratio']).agg({'count': max})
coll_g = coll_g['count'].groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
coll_g = coll_g.nlargest(1)
coll_g
```

Here I'm getting the class whose occurrence is maximum but i'm not getting the max. frequency no.
The output I get is -

```
17743754 - 1  MEAT & LIVESTOCK            1
17743759 - 1  ANIMAL AND VEGETABLE OIL    1
17743970 - 1  IRON ORE                    1
17743996 - 1  OTHER GOODS                 1
```

I'm using Pandas .20 and python 3.6.3

Can you guys suggest me where I'm going wrong and what should be my code.

Comment: Perhaps you might after `.groupby(...).transform('max')`

Comment: @Dark -  thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html), what return max category because before [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and `max` to new `DataFrame` and then `join` to original `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.groupby(['FileName'])['Class_par_ratio'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Freq')

df1 = df.set_index('Class_par_ratio').groupby(['FileName'])['Freq'].agg(['idxmax','max'])

d = {'idxmax':'Max_Class','max':'Max Freq.'}
df = df.join(df1, on='FileName').rename(columns=d)
```

Or use double [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['FileName'])['Class_par_ratio'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Freq')

g = df.set_index('Class_par_ratio').groupby(['FileName'])['Freq']
df['Max_Class'] = g.transform('idxmax').values
df['Max Freq.'] = g.transform('max').values
print (df)
       FileName           Class_par_ratio  Freq Max_Class  Max Freq.
0  17973375 - 1                      MILK     4      MILK          4
1  17973375 - 1  ANIMAL AND VEGETABLE OIL     1      MILK          4
2  17973375 - 1               OTHER FOODS     1      MILK          4
```

Verifying solution for second sample data:

```
df1 = df.set_index('Class_par_ratio').groupby(['FileName'])['Frequency'].agg(['idxmax','max'])
d = {'idxmax':'Max_Class','max':'Max Freq.'}
df = df.join(df1, on='FileName').rename(columns=d)
print (df)
       FileName Class_par_ratio  Frequency    Max_Class  Max Freq.
0  17743633 - 1      OTHE FOODS          2  OTHER GOODS          4
1  17743633 - 1     OTHER GOODS          4  OTHER GOODS          4
2  17743634 - 1            MEAT         12         MEAT         12
3  17743634 - 2            MEAT          1         MEAT          1
4  17743635 - 1            MEAT         83         MEAT         83
5  17743635 - 1     OTHER GOODS          2         MEAT         83
6  17743642 - 1            MEAT         43         MEAT         43
7  17743642 - 1     OTHER GOODS          2         MEAT         43
8  17743739 - 1     OTHER GOODS          3  OTHER GOODS          3
```

If need remove duplicated values add [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
cols = ['Max_Class','Max Freq.']
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df['FileName'].duplicated())
print (df)
       FileName Class_par_ratio  Frequency    Max_Class  Max Freq.
0  17743633 - 1      OTHE FOODS          2  OTHER GOODS        4.0
1  17743633 - 1     OTHER GOODS          4          NaN        NaN
2  17743634 - 1            MEAT         12         MEAT       12.0
3  17743634 - 2            MEAT          1         MEAT        1.0
4  17743635 - 1            MEAT         83         MEAT       83.0
5  17743635 - 1     OTHER GOODS          2          NaN        NaN
6  17743642 - 1            MEAT         43         MEAT       43.0
7  17743642 - 1     OTHER GOODS          2          NaN        NaN
8  17743739 - 1     OTHER GOODS          3  OTHER GOODS        3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the requirements got changed and the columns that i wanted were - **FileName,Class_par_ratio, Confidence.**
Here confidence is nothing but ((freq/max_freq)*100)
If the value is more than 80 then output HIGH.
If the value is between 60-80 then output MEDIUM, else LOW.
the output would look like -

```
FileName        COMM_CODE           Confidence
17743633 - 1    OTHER GOODS         MEDIUM
17743634 - 1    MEAT & LIVESTOCK    HIGH
17743634 - 2    MEAT & LIVESTOCK    HIGH
17743635 - 1    MEAT & LIVESTOCK    HIGH
```

Following is the code that i wrote to get to this output-

```
mf = (df.groupby(['FileName'])['COMM_CODE'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Freq'))
we = mf.groupby(['FileName'])['Freq'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(6).sum()).reset_index(name='Tot')
mf = mf.groupby(['FileName']).first().reset_index()

mf['Confidence_%'] = (mf['Freq']/we['Tot'])*100

mf['Confidence'] = ['HIGH' if x >= 80.0 else 'MEDIUM' if x>=60.0 else 'LOW' for x in mf['Confidence_%']]
mf.drop(['Freq','Confidence_%'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```